# javascript code doesnt work in browser

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this code and I am using PsPad editor when I am programing. When I run "HTML Page preview" in PsPad it works but when I try open it in browser it does't work. On Chrome it only alerts "Undefined is not a function". On Firefox it only prints undefined and alerts empty window. On Internet Explorer it does nothing. Can you give me some simple answer with code example if possible?(This code should print content of XML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var xmldoc= loadXMLDoc('skoly.xml');

            var d = document.createElement('div'); 
            var t = document.createTextNode(xmldoc.xml); 
            d.appendChild(t);
            document.write('<pre>' + d.innerHTML + '</pre>');

            alert(xmldoc.xml);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

loadxmldoc.js:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    try { //Internet Explorer
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    } catch(e) {
        try { //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
            xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e.message)
        }
    }
    try {
        xmlDoc.async=false;
        xmlDoc.load(dname);
        return(xmlDoc);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e.message)
    }
    return(null);
}
```

Comment: And which line the error message points to?

Comment: You need to provide more details about the error. What does it say is undefined?

Comment: e.message is undefined indeed..

Comment: Oh I see, you're talking about the alert. Try to use the [error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) instead of using `alert()` to debug.

Comment: Ok i tryed it on Chrom and console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xml' of null "

Answer (score 0):

your declaration for instantiating an object of XMLHttpRequest for Firefox/Chrome is incorrect, to correctly instantiate, do the following:

```
var xmldoc = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

to get document from same domain(can't get from different domain for security reasons), you use the open method for xml.

```
xml.open(method, url, boolean);
xml.send(null);   // if using post, then you will send data and not null*

// method - GET or POST
// url - location to the file being loaded
// bool - true or false(true for asynchronous)
```

This is the simplest function to get files with ajax:

```
<script>
    function loadxmldoc(method, url)
    {
        var xml;
        try
        {
            xml = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert('Couldn\'t instantiate ajax');
            }
        }

        xml.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200 )
            {    // ajax ready           // page found
                document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = xml.responseText;
            }
        };

        xml.open(method, url, true);    // open connection
        xml.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

i am using `xml.responseText` and for you it should be `xml.responseXml` and you have to parse it correctly.

Comment: The try..catch block sets the value of `e`. The OP is trying to debug the script, not create a custom error message.

Comment: var xmldoc = new XMLHttpRequest(); gived me this :"xmlDoc is not defined"

Comment: if you are trying to load a document from somewhere then there is a format used in AJAX. let me edit the answer

Comment: Sorry but I am lost. Function loadxmldoc should return XML object and this doesnt look like it does.

Comment: it returns xml object..replace `xml.responseText` with `xml.responseXml`

Answer (score 0):

This part is returning the error:

```
alert(xmldoc.xml);
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but this code is trying to return a property "xml" of variable "xmldoc". In other words, this would work if xmldoc was an object which looks like this:

```
var xmldoc = {
    xml: "something here"
};
```

It is returning "Cannot read property 'xml' of null" because xmldoc has value null and you are trying to return its property.

Comment: I dont know, but when i run it in PsPad i does it right.